# DAX - Calculate previous day

Tags: dax, selectedvalue

I have a DAX formula for a measure as below

```
PreviousDay = PREVIOUSDAY(SELECTEDVALUE(B32_VS_PERIODS[DATE_BEGIN]))
```

But this formula is giving me A function ‘SELECTEDVALUE’ has been used in a true-false expression that is used as a table filter expression. This is not allowed.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

The `PREVIOUSDAY` function expects a date column as its argument.

You can simply write `SELECTEDVALUE(B32_VS_PERIODS[DATE_BEGIN]) - 1` instead.